# ArcGIS Pro Join works one way but not other

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins, table

To make this map I added a Building field to the feature layer. I also made a standalone table by using a SQL Query. For some reason when I try to join the two tables together I can join the feature layer on the query layer but not the other way around.

[image: Fields from the feature layer table]

[image: Fields from the query layer]

[image: Join on query layer]

[image: Join on feature layer]

All values are showing Null when there is clearly values in the standalone table.

Comment: You could try some shots in the dark such as changing the type of  tables (try dbf), turning off maintaining fully qualified fields names, clear M values, or even try doing a spatial join.